# pygame rect is slipping out of the mouse curser

Tags: python, pygame

I have  a method which moves rects around when you drag them
everything is working good except that when I move the mouse fast it ends up outside the rect therefore making the rect stop moving
even though I am setting the rect center to the mouse pos

**so, How can I make the rect never slip out of the mouse curser?**

```
def play_card(self, events):
    global mousebutton
    mousebutton = pg.mouse.get_pressed()
    for index, card in enumerate(self.cards_rects):
        posx,posy = pg.mouse.get_pos()
        if mousebutton[0] and card.collidepoint(posx, posy):
            print("clicked")
            self.clicked = True
        else:
            self.clicked = False
            
        if self.clicked:
            x,y  = pg.mouse.get_pos()
            self.cards_rects[index].center= x,y
```

Comment: Hint: what things need to be true in order for it to make sense to set `self.clicked = False`? In the existing code, will this happen if `card.collidepoint(posx, posy)` fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this part of the code:

```
if mousebutton[0] and card.collidepoint(posx, posy):
    print("clicked")
    self.clicked = True
else:
    self.clicked = False
```

The `else` means that `self.clicked` will be set `False` whenever **either** the mouse is released (`not mousebutton[0]`) **or** the mouse escapes from the card by a quick movement (`not card.collidepoint(posx, posy)`). So the quick movement will cause the card to be dropped.

If the mouse is outside of the card, there are two possibilities:

- We were not already dragging the card, and we are still not dragging the card. So `self.clicked` should be `False`, but it was **already** `False`, so we don't need to do anything.
- We *were* dragging the card, and we will still be dragging the card. So again, we don't need to do anything; `self.clicked` was `True`, and should still be `True`.

We **only** want to actually set the value back to `False` if the mouse button is released, so we can e.g. replace the `else` with `elif`:

```
if mousebutton[0] and card.collidepoint(posx, posy):
    print("clicked")
    self.clicked = True
elif not mousebutton[0]:
    self.clicked = False
```

Another way to do this logic:

```
if not mousebutton[0]:
    self.clicked = False
elif card.collidepoint(posx, posy):
    self.clicked = True
```

That way avoids repeating the mention of `mousebutton`. If we get to the `elif`, we already know that `mousebutton[0]` is set, since otherwise the `if` branch would have been taken.

Comment: that worked like butter!

Comment: sorry for not marking your answer as correct till now

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using the `MOUSEBUTTONDOWN`, `MOUSEBUTTONUP` and `MOUSEMOTION` event for dragging. Test if the mouse collides with the object, set an attribute indicating that the dragging has started and calculate the position of the mouse relative to the object in `MOUSEBUTTONDOWN`:

```py
if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
    self.dragging = self.rect.collidepoint(event.pos)
    self.rel_pos = event.pos[0] - self.rect.x, event.pos[1] - self.rect.y
```

Set the new position in 'MOUSEMOTION' depending on the new mouse position when in drag mode:

```py
if event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION and self.dragging:
    self.rect.topleft = event.pos[0] - self.rel_pos[0], event.pos[1] - self.rel_pos[1]
```

End dragging in `MOUSEBUTTONUP`:

```py
if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
    self.dragging = False
```

---

Minimal example:

[image]

```py
import pygame

class DragOperator:
    def __init__(self, rect):
        self.rect = rect
        self.dragging = False
        self.rel_pos = (0, 0)
    def update(self, event_list):
        for event in event_list:
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                self.dragging = self.rect.collidepoint(event.pos)
                self.rel_pos = event.pos[0] - self.rect.x, event.pos[1] - self.rect.y
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                self.dragging = False
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION and self.dragging:
                self.rect.topleft = event.pos[0] - self.rel_pos[0], event.pos[1] - self.rel_pos[1]

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

rectangle = pygame.Rect(0, 0, 40, 40)
rectangle.center = window.get_rect().center
drag_rectangle = DragOperator(rectangle)

run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(60)
    event_list = pygame.event.get()
    for event in event_list:
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    drag_rectangle.update(event_list)
    rectangle_color = (0, 255, 0) if drag_rectangle.dragging else (255, 0, 0)

    window.fill(0)
    pygame.draw.rect(window, rectangle_color, rectangle)
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
exit()
```

Comment: That's some impressive speed for a full demo.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I had the example at hand in my "Pygame" repository

Comment: Oh. The question isn't a duplicate, then?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel No, I have never used this example on Stack Overflow. However, there are a lot of similar questions around here and I am very sure that you can find a duplicate with some searching effort.

Comment: I'm bookmarking this question for later. I have a looming dread that there "are a lot of similar questions around here", but none of them are better asked or answered than this one....

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Yes, that might be the case.